# two CNAME records pointing to the same url

Tags: cname-record

Can I have two CNAME records that point to the same url?

Example: **www** CNAME to my.website.com and **shop** CNAME to my.website.com

Will they both work at the same time?

Comment: CNAMEs point to host/domain names, they don't point to URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There is no such limitation as the lookup will check for the requested entry and won't even notice that other entries point to the same place.

Comment: Thanks Julie. I will try to add a CNAME record that points to another existing domain. :)